# Best practice for an UI overlay positioning system?

Tags: gui-design

User wishes to upload and position their image as an overlay in the video player.

Proposed solution allows the user to see the thumbnail of the video with a grid from which they may select a desired position. In certain contexts they also see the change reflected directly on the player, while in some they do not see the player.

Could you kindly propose any recommendations for further improvements or ways to simplify the interaction?

[image: selecting the overlay image position]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to reference the video-player (on the left of your gif) as the user already has the video-frame where he is interacting. Rather than showing the video-frame twice **I would only display it once**, where the user is interacting, in a bigger size.

**The "example" could follow the mouse cursor** (respecting the position on the grid) while it moves, instead of changing position when the user clicks. If you follow this suggestion, you don't need to display the white square that in your example is following the mouse.

If you want opinions also on the grid, I would suggest you consider a grid that gives more possibilities (a 5*5 grid for example) to place the user "example". But this depends on the purpose of those images and their size.

Comment: Using the "example" as the cursor is ingenious. That will be implemented.

Great point on the grid also as it leads to my primary concern regarding the clarity. The 3x3 grid in place I feel doesn't communicate that the content will be expanded in reverse direction so if in the top left square, the content will expand right and below, if in the middle square, content will expand to all sides equally.

I tried indicating the expansion direction with arrows but that looked ridiculous, maybe I will be able to combine the arrows with the newly created cursor. Thoughts?

Comment: @PetarSubotic could explain or give an example what you mean with: "The 3x3 grid in place I feel doesn't communicate that the content will be expanded in reverse direction"